# request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'customer'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, razorpay

Was implementing the razorpay,got the above error.
I need to create a new customer in the razorpay api.
unable to get the customer as it is saying the error is unable to get customer.

```
from django.db import models
from customers.models import Customer
from django.db.models.signals import post_save,pre_save
import razorpay

client = razorpay.Client(auth=("", ""))

class BillingProfile(models.Model):
customer      = models.OneToOneField(Customer,null=True,blank=True)
inserted      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
b_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.customer.name

def billing_profile_recieved(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
if not instance.b_customer_id and instance.customer:
    print(instance.id,"OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoo")
    print(client,"------------------------------")
    customer = client.customer.create(customer=instance.id)  //_______ ERROR
    print(customer)
pre_save.connect(billing_profile_recieved,sender=BillingProfile)


def user_created_reciever(sender,instance,created,*args,**kwargs):
if created:
    BillingProfile.objects.get_or_create(customer=instance)
print(instance.user_customer,client)

post_save.connect(user_created_reciever, sender=Customer)
```

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback, and indent the code properly.

Comment: that is *not* the traceback, furthermore please [edit] the question. Since a traceback is multiline, it would make a total mess in comments.

Comment: Yes,sure.I'll do the same.@WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

```
name = instance.customer.name
email = instance.customer.user_customer.email
contact = instance.customer.phone_no

if not instance.b_customer_id and instance.customer:
    try:
        customer = client.customer.create(     {
                                            "name" : name,
                                            "email" : email,
                                            "contact" : contact,
                                            "notes": {}
                                            }
                                    )
        instance.b_customer_id = customer["id"]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

pre_save.connect(billing_profile_recieved,sender=BillingProfile)
```

This is way is I should have passed the data.
This format was integrated in their api.

Answer (score 0):

May be because user with Email already existing. You can pass an additional parameter called "fail_existing":"0" . Then the customer_id will be returned. If there is no existing customer, it will create a new customer and return customer_id.

The body should be something like this:

```
{
  "name" : "Cornelius123",
  "email" : "cornelius19901@gmail.com",
  "contact" : "+919000000000",
  "fail_existing":"0",
  "notes": {}
}
```

[image: img]