# request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'amount' in razorpay integration with django

Tags: python, django, razorpay

I am trying to integrate Razorpay with my django application,

As suggested in their [documentation](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/#capture-a-payment) I did,

```
pip install razorpay
```

and Now I'm trying to create an order by doing,

```
client = razorpay.Client(auth=("<key>", "<secret>"))
resp = client.order.create(amount=5000, currency='INR', receipt='TR110462011',
                                   payment_capture='1')
```

But I'm getting,

> request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'amount'

I referred,
[request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'customer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672428/request-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-customer)

But it was not much of a help.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Check --> https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-python/blob/2f27c6d0f3e35dab972132ecd67851f68976aaf4/README.md#orders

You have to pass the data as a dict

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to their API documentation [here](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-python/blob/2f27c6d0f3e35dab972132ecd67851f68976aaf4/README.md#orders) you need to pass a dictionary.

So, you can just modify your code by wrapping your arguments in `dict()` and it will work.

```py
client = razorpay.Client(auth=("<key>", "<secret>"))
resp = client.order.create(dict(amount=5000, currency='INR', receipt='TR110462011', payment_capture='1'))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I don't understand why haven't they changed this on their main documentation page!?!