# razorpay.errors.BadRequestError: The amount must be an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, razorpay

#### ***razorpay.errors.BadRequestError: The amount must be an integer.***

Hi, i am trying to test a web app with razorpay on test mode. The amount i pass is an integer and is under 5 digits.I am still  getting this error. Any Help is appreciated

here is the code that i am using:

```py
            order_amount = int(99 * 100)
            order_currency = 'INR'
            order_receipt = 'order_rcptid_'+user.user_name                  
            order = razorpay_client.order.create(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency, receipt=order_receipt)
```

**Here is the stack trace:**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2021 21:16:25] "GET /checkout HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Code/deploy/flask-ecommerce-project/userController.py", line 209, in checkout
    order = razorpay_client.order.create(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency, receipt=order_receipt)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/razorpay/resources/order.py", line 71, in create
    return self.post_url(url, data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/razorpay/resources/base.py", line 20, in post_url
    return self.client.post(url, data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/razorpay/client.py", line 155, in post
    return self.request('post', path, data=data, **options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/razorpay/client.py", line 121, in request
    **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 567, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'amount'
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2021 21:16:25] "GET /checkout?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2021 21:16:25] "GET /checkout?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2021 21:16:25] "GET /checkout?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2021 21:16:25] "GET /checkout?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 20
```

Comment: Looks like you are passing an `int`. But we are not sure if you're sending the data in the right format, if you're missing a field, etc. This error is specific to the RazorPay API

Comment: Yes I made a mistake in the format thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

According to Razorpay docs for order creation here: https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/
The correct format of order creation is:

```
import razorpay client = razorpay.Client(auth=("YOUR_ID", "YOUR_SECRET"))
order_amount = 50000
order_currency = 'INR'
order_receipt = 'order_rcptid_11'
notes = {'Shipping address': 'Bommanahalli, Bangalore'} #OPTIONAL
client.order.create(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency, receipt=order_receipt, notes=notes)
```

You are passing the required data as 1 parameter in object form while it requires the data passed directly to the parameters.

Comment: But when I use this format I get a new error `TypeError: request () got an unexpected keyword argument 'amount'`.Anyways Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you passing the parameter name in the form of a string, like client.order.create('amount'=order_amount, .....)?

Comment: No I am passing it as per the docs. ```order = razorpay_client.order.create(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency, receipt=order_receipt)```

Comment: Can you post the updated code as well as the stack trace?

Comment: i have posted the updated code and the stack trace

Comment: Hi. Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891635/request-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-amount-in-razorpay-integration-wi
Looks like even their documentation is not updated correctly

Comment: I have tried out this solution and it has returned to the same error that i first posted about

Comment: Update I have solved this issue. The problem was in the line ```order_amount = int(Total * 100)``` When i printed the order amount it produced a huge number with tens of digits.When i change it to ```order_amount = int(Total)*100``` it returns the proper number.Thanks for your help and effort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232135/discussion-between-adityan-p-and-shubham-jawandhiya).

Answer (score 1):

according to api specification https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/ , you have to pass all the parameters separately, In your case you are passing a dictionary which contains all the parameters.

```
        order_amount = int(99 * 100)  #9900
        order_currency = 'INR'
        order_receipt = 'order_rcptid_11'
```

code below passes a dictionary as param

```
    order = razorpay_client.order.create({ 'amount' : order_amount, 'currency' : order_currency, 'receipt' : order_receipt, 'payment_capture' : '1'})
```

replace it with this code which passes the params separately.

```
client.order.create(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency, receipt=order_receipt, notes=notes)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but as you can see from the comment on the above answer I am getting a new error and I can't seem to figure it out